# How to handle customer visit problem @SpringBootApplication public class ExamCustomerCheckApplication

Tags: java

To ignore a specific field or property during JSON serialization/deserialization, you can use annotations provided by the Jackson library, which is commonly used in Java for JSON processing.

In this case, if you want to ignore the "other" field in the PokemonSprites class, you can use the @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation at the class level. Here's an example:
In the findByProductProductId method, we specify the property path product.productId to indicate that we want to search by the productId of the associated Product entity.
package fact.it.examcustomercheck.entities;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class Visit {

```
private int enterWeight;
private int exitWeight;

private Customer customer;

public int getEnterWeight() {
    return enterWeight;
}

public void setEnterWeight(int enterWeight) {
    this.enterWeight = enterWeight;
}

public int getExitWeight() {
    return exitWeight;
}

public void setExitWeight(int exitWeight) {
    this.exitWeight = exitWeight;
}

public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

public int getDepositedWeight() {
    return this.enterWeight - this.exitWeight;
}

public int getMembershipAge() {
    int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    return year - this.customer.getYearOfRegistration();
}

public int getCost() {
    if (getDepositedWeight() <= 7 && getMembershipAge() > 5) {
        return 0;
    } else if (getDepositedWeight() <= 50) {
        return getDepositedWeight() * 2;
    } else {
        return getDepositedWeight() * 3;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.customer.getName() + " registered in " + this.customer.getYearOfRegistration() +
            " has deposited " + getDepositedWeight() + "kg. of waste: Cost = " + getCost() + " euro.";
}
```

}

package fact.it.examcustomercheck.entities;

public class Customer {

```
private String name;
private boolean citizen;
private int yearOfRegistration;

public Customer() {

}

public Customer(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Customer(String name, boolean citizen, int yearOfRegistration) {
    this.name = name;
    this.citizen = citizen;
    this.yearOfRegistration = yearOfRegistration;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isCitizen() {
    return citizen;
}

public void setCitizen(boolean citizen) {
    this.citizen = citizen;
}

public int getYearOfRegistration() {
    return yearOfRegistration;
}

public void setYearOfRegistration(int yearOfRegistration) {
    this.yearOfRegistration = yearOfRegistration;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    if (citizen) {
        return this.name + " (citizen) registered in " + this.yearOfRegistration;
    } else {
        return this.name + " registered in " + this.yearOfRegistration;
    }
}
```

}

@SpringBootApplication
public class ExamCustomerCheckApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ExamCustomerCheckApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've done it at field level using `@JsonIgnore`, with the following import statement `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore`

using the above example

So you could do something like:

```
@JsonIgnore 
private Customer customer;
```